# how to create wordpress image thumbnail metadata (size / exif / iptc) in c# .net

Tags: c#, wordpress, image, metadata, exif

this is ane xample of wordpress thumbnail image metadata :

```
a:6:{s:5:"width";i:250;s:6:"height";i:150;s:14:"hwstring_small";s:23:"height='77' width='128'";s:4:"file";s:33:"2014/09/13920503000128_PhotoA.jpg";s:5:"sizes";a:5:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:33:"13920503000128_PhotoA-150x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:14:"post-thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"13920503000128_PhotoA-100x65.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:65;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:9:"art-thumb";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:32:"13920503000128_PhotoA-100x65.jpg";s:5:"width";i:100;s:6:"height";i:65;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:7:"art-gal";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:33:"13920503000128_PhotoA-210x150.jpg";s:5:"width";i:210;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}s:10:"td_198x143";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:33:"13920503000128_PhotoA-198x143.jpg";s:5:"width";i:198;s:6:"height";i:143;s:9:"mime-type";s:10:"image/jpeg";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:11:{s:8:"aperture";i:0;s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";i:0;s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";i:0;s:3:"iso";i:0;s:13:"shutter_speed";i:0;s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";i:0;}}
```

How can i make it with c#?
I don't know about this parameters : (example) s:10 or i:0 or a:4 or s:33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at a serialized PHP variable.

- s:10 is a string with a length of 10 (see s:5:"width")
- i:0 is an integer '0'
- a:4 is an array with 4 entries

Here is a breakdown of what everything is taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php#66147

> ### Anatomy of a serialize()'ed value:
>
> **String:**
>   s:size:value; (String values are always in double quotes)
>
> **Integer:**
>   i:value;
>
> **Boolean:**
>   b:value; (does not store "true" or "false", does store '1' or '0')
>
> **Null:**
>   N;
>
> **Array:**
>   a:size:{key definition;value definition;(repeated per element)}
>   Array keys are always integers or strings
>
> > "null => 'value'" equates to 's:0:"";s:5:"value";',
> >     "true => 'value'" equates to 'i:1;s:5:"value";',
> >     "false => 'value'" equates to 'i:0;s:5:"value";',
> >
> > "array(whatever the contents) => 'value'" equates to an "illegal offset type" warning because you can't use an
> >         array as a key; however, if you use a variable containing an array as a key, it will equate to 's:5:"Array";s:5:"value";',
> >          and attempting to use an object as a key will result in the same behavior as using an array will.
>
> **Object:**
>   O:strlen(object name):object name:object size:{s:strlen(property name):property name:property definition;(repeated per property)}

Here is the first array in your metadata unserialized:

(remember array keys in php can be strings. php arrays are pretty much hash maps)

```
Array
(
    [width] => 250
    [height] => 150
    [hwstring_small] => "height='77' width='128'"
    [file] => "2014/09/13920503000128_PhotoA.jpg"
    [sizes] => Array
    (
        [thumbnail] => Array
        (
            [file] => "13920503000128_PhotoA-150x150.jpg"
            [width] => 150
            [height] => 150
            [mime-type] => "image/jpeg"
        )
    ...
```

You can unserialize the rest [here](http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/)